# Matlab YTick and XTick values

Tags: matlab

I need to get all values represented in a plot (on Y and on X axis too). I used `YTick` and `XTick`, but there are some situations when `get()` function doesn't get me all the represents values (it doesn't matter what axis is).

For example:
- let's say we have the next values on X axis of the plot: `0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8`
- `XTick` gives me only `0 2 4 6 8` values :(

How is it possible that `XTick` gives me values that don't match with all the values from the plot?

 I have also tried to use `YMinorTick` and `XMinorTick`, and it didn't help either...

Please give me some solution if you know!
Thank you!

Comment: Please show how you are implementing this with code and exactly what you're expecting to happen

Comment: Ok! Let's say i create a figure like this:  plot(x,y); hold on; plot(x,z);  Where x=[0 1], y = [0 0], z=[-0.36 -0.36]. In this case Matlab will create a figure which has on YAxis: [-0.4 -0.35 -0.3 -0.25 -0.2 -0.15 -0.1 -0.05 0] values, and on XAxis: [0 0.1 0.2 0.3 0.4 0.5 0.6 0.7 0.8 0.9 1]. When i try to get YTick values, using this: ha=gca(); ytick=get(ha,'ytick'), it gives me this vector: [-0.4 -0.3 -0.2 -0.1 0]. Why i need the exact values?

Comment: Because i want to "zoom in" the plot. Adjusting minimum and maximum values on both axes such as the represented values will not be represented on the limit of the plot, like default representation. For the adjustment i wanted to get the "step" on every axes and find the minimum and maximum represented values, and make this adjustment: newXAxisMinValue=currentXAxisMinValue - xStep; newXAxisMaxValue=currentXAxisMaxValue + xStep; (same for Y axis).

Comment: Your question is not clear to me either. But maybe you should set/get the TickValues right before you watch them.

Comment: @stormhold Can you post some code that reproduces the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the proper figure and axis selected.  One way to do this is by clicking on the axis you want and then doing `get(gca,'XTick')` where `gca` gives you the handle of the current axis (you can do `help gca` for more info).  You can also select it by using `figure(f)` and `subplot()` (with the right arguments) to go back to the figure and subplot you're interested in.

There's other ways to do it, but make sure your current axis is the one you're `get`ing.

Or post your precise code for the `get()` call.

Finally, if you're just trying to zoom, why don't you just use the `axis` command.  Like this `axis([xmin xmax ymin ymax]);`